# Wagtail 4 Upgrade: 'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

After reading through and updating possible breaking changes stated in the Wagtail [changelog](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/4.0.html), I am getting the following error when viewing any edit menu for any page:

```
'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://example.com/admin/pages/530/edit/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'
Exception Location: /home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/blocks/base.py, line 526, in block_json
Python Executable:  /home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/bin/python3.10
Python Version: 3.10.9
Python Path:    
['/home/user/projects/mysite/django',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/home/user/projects/mysite/django/mysite']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Oct 2023 11:02:12 -0500
Error during template rendering

In template /home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/panels/object_list.html, error at line 9
'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'
1   {% load wagtailadmin_tags %}
2   
3   <div class="w-form-width">
4       {% if self.help_text %}
5           {% help_block status="info" %}{{ self.help_text }}{% endhelp_block %}
6       {% endif %}
7       {% for child, identifier in self.visible_children_with_identifiers %}
8           {% panel id_prefix=self.prefix id=identifier classname=child.classes|join:' ' heading=child.heading heading_size="label" icon=child.icon id_for_label=child.id_for_label is_required=child.is_required %}
9               {% component child %}
10          {% endpanel %}
11      {% endfor %}
12  </div>
13
```

The full stack trace is the following:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://example.com/admin/pages/530/edit/

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.10.9
Installed Applications:
['six',
 'formtools',
 'django_otp',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
 'two_factor',
 'apps.content_blocks',
 'apps.pages.home',
 'apps.pages.utility',
 'apps.pages.search',
 'apps.pages.blank_slate',
 'apps.rates',
 'apps.utils',
 'apps.pages.puput',
 'wagtail.contrib.sitemaps',
 'wagtail.contrib.routable_page',
 'apps.wagtailstreamforms',
 'crispy_forms',
 'apps.wagtail_admin_extension',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.contrib.search_promotions',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail',
 'apps.pages.group_testimonials',
 'apps.pages.emergency_notifications',
 'apps.pages.promotions_carousel',
 'apps.pages.locations',
 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
 'wagtailmenus',
 'wagtail.contrib.table_block',
 'wagtail.contrib.styleguide',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'user_sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'sekizai',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'rest_framework',
 'wagtailmetadata',
 'wagtail.api.v2',
 'tinymce',
 'wagtail.contrib.frontend_cache',
 'gunicorn']
Installed Middleware:
['user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'x_forwarded_for.middleware.XForwardedForMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/panels/object_list.html, error at line 9
   'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'
   1 : {% load wagtailadmin_tags %}
   2 : 
   3 : <div class="w-form-width">
   4 :     {% if self.help_text %}
   5 :         {% help_block status="info" %}{{ self.help_text }}{% endhelp_block %}
   6 :     {% endif %}
   7 :     {% for child, identifier in self.visible_children_with_identifiers %}
   8 :         {% panel id_prefix=self.prefix id=identifier classname=child.classes|join:' ' heading=child.heading heading_size="label" icon=child.icon id_for_label=child.id_for_label is_required=child.is_required %}
   9 :              {% component child %} 
   10 :         {% endpanel %}
   11 :     {% endfor %}
   12 : </div>
   13 : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 197, in overridden_render
    return render()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels.py", line 405, in render_form_content
    return mark_safe(self.render_html() + self.render_missing_fields())
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/ui/components.py", line 20, in render_html
    return template.render(context_data)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/ui/components.py", line 20, in render_html
    return template.render(context_data)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templatetags/wagtailadmin_tags.py", line 995, in render
    children = self.nodelist.render(context) if self.nodelist else ""
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templatetags/wagtailadmin_tags.py", line 923, in component
    return obj.render_html(context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/ui/components.py", line 15, in render_html
    context_data = self.get_context_data(parent_context)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels.py", line 842, in get_context_data
    rendered_field = self.bound_field.as_widget(attrs=widget_attrs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 93, in as_widget
    return widget.render(
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/blocks/base.py", line 554, in render
    return self.render_with_errors(
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/blocks/base.py", line 548, in render_with_errors
    block_json=self.block_json,
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs_dev/mysite/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/blocks/base.py", line 525, in block_json
    return self._block_json

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/530/edit/
Exception Value: 'BlockWidget' object has no attribute '_block_json'
```

I've used python poetry in attempt to have all libraries compatible. It builds just fine and the site runs. It is just this specific portion of the site that has to do with the actual Wagtail package that keeps failing. Any idea what could be wrong?

The libraries/versions I am using are:

```
Babel="2.9.1"
backcall="0.2.0"
bcrypt="3.2.0"
beautifulsoup4="4.9.3"
bleach="4.1.0"
boto3="1.19.11"
botocore="1.22.11"
certifi="2019.11.28"
cffi="1.15.1"
chardet="4.0.0"
click="8.0.3"
cryptography="3.3.2"
decorator="4.4.2"
Django="3.2.9"
django-appconf="1.0.5"
django-bakery="0.12.7"
django-classy-tags="2.0.0"
django-compressor="2.4.1"
django-crispy-forms="1.13.0"
django-debug-toolbar="3.2.2"
django-el-pagination="3.3.0"
django-environ="0.8.1"
django-extensions="3.1.3"
django-filter="2.4.0"                                                              
django-formtools="2.2"
django-model-utils="4.2.0"
django-modelcluster="6.1"
django-multi-email-field="0.6.2"
django-otp="1.1.1"
django-phonenumber-field="5.2.0"
django-recaptcha="2.0.6"
django-redis="5.0.0"
django-redis-cache="3.0.0"
django-sekizai="2.0.0"
django-taggit="3.1.0"
django-tinymce4-lite="1.8.0"
django-treebeard="4.5.1"
django-two-factor-auth="1.13.1"
django-user-sessions="1.7.1"
django-xforwardedfor-middleware="2.0"
djangorestframework="3.12.4"
docutils="0.17.1"
draftjs-exporter="2.1.7"
ecdsa="0.17.0"
elasticsearch="7.15.1"
entrypoints="0.3"
Fabric3="1.14.post1"
fastnumbers="3.2.1"
gevent="21.8.0"
greenlet="1.1.2"
gunicorn="20.1.0"
html5lib="1.1"
idna="3.3"
imagesize="1.3.0"
ipdb="0.13.9"
ipykernel="5.5.6"
ipyparallel="6.3.0"
ipython="7.17.0"
ipython-genutils="0.2.0"
ipywidgets="7.6.5"
jedi="0.18.0"
Jinja2="3.0.2"
jmespath="0.10.0"
jsmin="3.0.0"
jsonschema="3.2.0"
jupyter-client="7.0.6"
jupyter-core="4.9.1"
l18n="2020.6.1"
Markdown="2.6.11"
MarkupSafe="2.0.1"
mistune="0.8.4"
mock="4.0.3"
nbconvert="6.0.7"
nbformat="5.1.3"
nose="1.3.7"
notebook="6.4.5"
olefile="0.46"
pandocfilters="1.5.0"
paramiko="2.8.0"
parso="0.8.2"
pbr="5.7.0"
pexpect="4.8.0"
phonenumberslite="8.12.36"
pickleshare="0.7.5"
Pillow="8.4.0"
prompt-toolkit="3.0.22"
psycopg2="2.8.6"
ptyprocess="0.7.0"
pyasn1="0.4.8"
pycparser="2.20"
pycrypto="2.6.1"
Pygments="2.10.0"
PyNaCl="1.4.0"
python-dateutil="2.8.2"
python-dotenv="0.19.1"
pytz="2023.3"
PyYAML="6.0"
pyzmq="22.3.0"
qrcode="6.1"
qtconsole="5.1.1"
rcssmin="1.0.6"
redis="3.5.3"
requests="2.26.0"
rjsmin="1.1.0"
s3transfer="0.5.0"
simplegeneric="0.8.1"
six="1.16.0"
snowballstemmer="2.1.0"
Sphinx="4.2.0"
sphinxcontrib-websupport="1.2.4"
sqlparse="0.4.2"
terminado="0.12.1"
testpath="0.5.0"
tornado="6.1"
traitlets="4.3.3"
Unidecode="1.3.2"
urllib3="1.26.7"
virtualenv="15.1.0"
wagtail="4.1"
wagtail-metadata="4.0.2"
wagtailmenus="3.1.9"
wcwidth="0.2.5"
webencodings="0.5.1"
whitenoise="5.3.0"
widgetsnbextension="3.5.2"
Willow="1.4"
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback from the error message, please? (Use the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" link)

Comment: Of course. The question has been updated to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to match this one reported in wagtailstreamforms: https://github.com/labd/wagtailstreamforms/issues/200

You don't have wagtailstreamforms listed in your packages, but it is listed in INSTALLED_APPS, so presumably it's included in your project's codebase. This needs to be upgraded to version 3.22 or later.